# Data from database into an array

Tags: php, arrays, database

```
<?php defined('WROOT') OR die('No direct script access.');

var_dump($channels_cat);

return array(
'category' => array(
      19 => array(
        'name' => 'Cars',
        'class' => 'channel17',
        'slug' => 'cars'
    ),
       4 => array(
        'name' => 'Food',
        'class' => 'channel2',
        'slug' => 'Food'
    ),

    19 => array(
        'name' => 'Fruit',
        'class' => 'channel7',
        'slug' => 'fruit'
    ),    
)
);

$channels['category']= db()->read('SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY priority ASC')->fetchAll();
foreach ($channels['category'] as $value):
$channels_cat[$value->category] =  $value->title;
endforeach;  
var_dump($channels_cat);
```

Well, I have this array created by me. I want to create another identical but using data from the database. In the database is 19, 4, 15 (IDs) and cars, fruit and food (category title) . I tried several times, but I failed.

Comment: I find the solution! :)
$category= db()->read('SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY priority ASC')->fetchAll();
     $category1 = array();
   foreach ($category as $value):
    $cat = $value->category;
    $category1[$cat] =  array('name' => ucfirst($value->title),
     'slug' => $value->title);

  endforeach;  
  $category_final = array( 'channels' => $category1);

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing the database? 

`` mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `some_database` WHERE id = '19' AND id = '4' AND id = '15'"); ``